# Waiting for task throws

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm just starting out with WinRT's concurrency model. I have a task that I need to wait on, but calling wait() throws an exception that I can't catch.

Simplest possible code:

```
concurrency::task<StorageFile^> getFileTask = concurrency::create_task(Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->GetFileAsync(fileString));
getFileTask.wait();
```

The exception it throws is:

```
Microsoft C++ exception: Concurrency::invalid_operation at memory location 0x0402C45C
```

How do I set this up so that it works?

Comment: are you calling this code from ui thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the most important rules that you must follow when building a Windows Store app is that you must never block the UI thread.  Never ever.

If you start an asynchronous operation, you get a `future` or `task` that "owns" that operation.  If you call `get()` or `wait()` on that operation before the asynchronous operation has completed, that call will *block* until the operation completes, then it will return the result.

Since blocking the UI thread is bad, if you attempt to synchronize with a not-yet-completed asynchronous operation on the UI thread, the call to `get()` or `wait()` will throw, to prevent the UI thread from being blocked.  This exception is there to help you to remember not to block the UI thread.  :-)

You should use `task`'s [`then()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750044.aspx) to provide a continuation that will run when the asynchronous operation completes.  If the continuation needs to run on the UI thread as well, be sure to pass `task_continuation_context::use_current()` to `then()` to ensure that the continuation is marshaled back to the UI thread for execution.

---

*Note:*  This exception is only thrown if you are using C++/CX.  If you are using C++ without the C++/CX language extensions, the call to `get()` or `wait()` will successfully block, potentially resulting in a poor user experience.  In general, C++/CX has many more "guard rail" features like this one that are designed to make it easier for you to write good code.  When using C++/CX, you get the full power of C++, with the understanding that there are more opportunities for error.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, wait() does not mean that the thread blocks, but only that the current execution is suspended, the thread can continue to run and handle messages